# CSS-only tabs piloting content of nested input tags

Tags: javascript, css

A series of CSS-only tabs

```
<ul class='tabs'>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab_23101" value="23101" checked />
    <label for='tab_23101'>      </label>
    <div id='tab-content_23101' class='tab-content'>   
      <label><input type="radio" class='imagepick' id="Frame_CD" name="Frame" value="23101_CD"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab_23102" value="23102" />
    <label for='tab_23102'>      </label>
    <div id='tab-content_23102' class='tab-content'>
      <label><input type="radio" class='imagepick' id="Frame_CD" name="Frame" value="23102_CD"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
```

each has specific content, which go on to specify for further inputs with names and values which are used by a javascript as selectors for rendering an image.  The problem is that a selected value in one line item `<li>` say `23101_CD` is not valid for the second line items (expecting `23102_CD`) and would thus render a blank if the second line item were selected.

the javascript is structured as follows

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
  var Frame_image =  $("input[name=tabs]:checked").val() + "_" + $("input[name=Frame]:checked").val();
  $("#Frame").attr("src", "/small/Frame_" +  Frame_image  + ".png");
```

How can one add pairs (multiple) of name and value to the parent input tag as part of the HTML (the desire is to avoid having to alter existing javascript) to act as selected items `checked="checked"`?

Comment: Kinda hard to follow this just from looking at the HTML and your explanation. A snippet showing how it actually works and what the problem is would be helpful.

Comment: Having a hard time parsing this question. What does this have to do with "CSS only"? Input tags generally can't have children. What exactly do you refer to by "parent input tag"?

Comment: @cjl750  a radio button by definition is for selecting.  You select that, but the child value for 'Frame' whatever is aleready checked may be invalid for another radio button selection.

Comment: @thykka  though resolves the issue indicating it is a dead end, if input tags cannot have children (while the CSS only is pertinent because it implies in itself an input value, and with the tabs the child relationship).

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear as to why you need input tags to have children. You can use adjacency selector (`+`) to match a tab next to a radiobutton. Here's a minimalist CSS-only tabs demo:

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.tabs > input {
  display: none;
}
.tabs > label {
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
.tabs > div {
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  order: 100;
  background: white;
}
.tabs > input:checked + label {
  background: white;
}
.tabs > input:not(:checked) + label + div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <input type="radio" name="t1" id="t1_1" checked/>
  <label for="t1_1">Tab 1</label>
  <div>
    Tab 1!
  </div>
  
  <input type="radio" name="t1" id="t1_2"/>
  <label for="t1_2">Tab 2</label>
  <div>
    Tab 2!
  </div>
  
  <input type="radio" name="t1" id="t1_3"/>
  <label for="t1_3">Tab 3</label>
  <div>
    Tab 3!
  </div>
</div>
```